# Bash recursive capturing of commands output

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to capture a command output and store it in a variable, but I would like to do it more then once.

For example, id'e like to do something like:

```
base=`basename `readlink link``
```

When I try this, I get an error:

```
basename: missing operand
```

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dollar parenthesis syntax for recursively capturing command output:

```
base=$(basename $(readlink link))
```

*The issue with the back-ticks is that when the interpreter encounters the second back-tick, the interpreter thinks the back-tick closes the first command whereas what you want is to open a new command.*